# Parsing data from a non csv file into multiple lists in python

Tags: python, information-retrieval

I have a text file which contains some really huge data which represents ratings given by users to specific movies. the structure of my file (.txt) is as such:

```
1:
1711859 ,4 ,2005 −05 −08
1245640 ,3 ,2005 −12 −19
2:
808731,4,2005−10−31
337541,5,2005−03−23
```

1 and 2 represent the movie ID's follow by a semi column then the user ID followed by the rating he gave to the movie and then the year.

Since this is clearly not a csv file, can someone please guide me on how to write a parser to read this file and create 2 lists. one for the movie ID's and the other, a list containing the ratings?

Comment: Load all lines, hopefully there aint too many of em, Find the indexes which contain `<id>:` and split the big list of lines into smaller lists, and then they are easier to use?

Answer (score 1):

> Since this is clearly not a csv file

Right, but it could be converted into csv file, let `file.txt` content be

```
1:
1711859 ,4 ,2005 −05 −08
1245640 ,3 ,2005 −12 −19
2:
808731,4,2005−10−31
337541,5,2005−03−23
```

then

```
with open("file.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as infile, open("file.csv","w",encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if "," not in line:
            movieid = line.split(":")[0]
        else:
            print(movieid,line,sep=",",end="",file=outfile)
```

will create `file.csv`

```
1,1711859 ,4 ,2005 −05 −08
1,1245640 ,3 ,2005 −12 −19
2,808731,4,2005−10−31
2,337541,5,2005−03−23
```

Which then could be feed into CSV parser. Explanation: If current line does not have `,` then get what is before `:` as movieid, otherwise print movieid followed by line sheared by `,`. Note that I set `end` to empty string as `line` already has it own newline. **Disclaimer**: I assume your file is UTF-8 encoded.